# Horizontal tabs in code blocks are a little broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

As the title says. Tabs are not 8 spaces from the beginning of the code block, but rather 8 spaces from the beginning of the line, making them 4 spaces short.

Current display:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
Release:    13
Codename:   Goddard
```

Should appear as:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
Release:        13
Codename:       Goddard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs are converted to four, not eight spaces.

Comment: I see. So then they're not broken so much as... inappropriately implemented. I can understand having them be fewer spaces on SO  where they're used in code, but on a site that reflects terminal display they should probably be 8 spaces.